# How to use manifest for disabling application cache?

Tags: angularjs, html, manifest, manifest.mf

I am writing a fairly complex HTML5 website making extensive use of AngularJS. The Website is hosted in a Python application on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk.

The file "**projectname/app/views/views.py**" looks like this:

```
from app import application
from flask import render_template

@application.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

The "**main.html**" looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='lib/google-maps/angular-google-maps.min.js') }}"></script> 

<!-- here are more javascript libs being loaded, also css files -->

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="applicationController">
  <div ng-include="'/static/partials/home/menu.html'"/>
  <div ng-include="'/static/partials/home/home.html'"/>
  <div ng-include="'/static/partials/home/footer.html'"/>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

The "**layout.html**" looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/static/manifest.mf">
<head lang="en"
      profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.png') }}"/>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Website title</title>


    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/colors.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/animations.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!-- more javascript libs loaded here ... -->

</head>
<body style="overflow-y: hidden">
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

In addition to these files I have dozens of html files that build up all parts of the website. These are included in the right places using ng-include.

What I experience is that whenever I deploy the website, all browsers seem to cache most of it and then only load parts of the new version which results in really really ugly behavior. For example, some javascript files are loaded in the new version, but html files are still old, so the views are really messy and lots of errors occur. When I reset the cache (for example in Chrome by pressing Shift-F5 under windows or by opening up the developer console and refreshing the website), everything is fine and the new version is loaded fully.

However, I cannot expect my customers to open up any development console whenever I redeploy a new version of the website.

So I read up some stuff about manifests, and as you can see I have a manifest.mf file referenced in the layout.html. Here is its content:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2016-01-07:v1.0.4

# This is the default section for entries. Files listed under this header (or immediately after the CACHE MANIFEST) will be explicitly cached after they're downloaded for the first time.
CACHE:
/static/img/login-background.jpg

# Files listed in this section may come from the network if they aren't in the cache, otherwise the network isn't used, even if the user is online. You can white-list specific URLs here, or simply "*", which allows all URLs. Most sites need "*".
NETWORK:
*

# An optional section specifying fallback pages if a resource is inaccessible. The first URI is the resource, the second is the fallback used if the network request fails or errors. Both URIs must from the same origin as the manifest file. You can capture specific URLs but also URL prefixes. "images/large/" will capture failures from URLs such as "images/large/whatever/img.jpg".
FALLBACK:
```

On every deployment, I change the first line and update the release date and version number. Also I add large images or files to the CACHE section (currently only some background image).

The manifest is also properly loaded, as can be seen from the Chrome developer console when loading the page. It says:

```
Creating Application Cache with manifest https://my.website.net/static/manifest.mf
my.website.net/:1 Application Cache Checking event
my.website.net/:1 Application Cache Downloading event
my.website.net/:1 Application Cache Progress event (0 of 1) https://my.website.net/static/img/login-background.jpg
my.website.net/:1 Application Cache Progress event (1 of 1) 
my.website.net/:1 Application Cache Cached event
```

So the cache file itself is working. However I still get half-updated pages whenever I deploy a new version. What can I do to fix this?

Any ideas are highly appreciated! Thanks a lot,
Christian

Comment: FYI is cache manifests now removed from the standard and is likely to be removed from the browsers in the future.  [Service workers]( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) seems to come in place, and is under consideration by the [Edge-team](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/serviceworker) too.

Comment: Thanks, @davidkonrad . this is good to know. I somehow suspect that there needs to be a different way of deploying websites, because the app cache as well as the service workers are designed for offline mode - which is not really what I want.

Comment: I can't believe no one ever came across deployment problems with html websites